# $\mathbb Z[X]/(2,X) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb Z[X]$ be the polynomial ring with integer coefficients. How do we know that $\mathbb Z[X]/(2,X) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more general fact is that $R[x]/(I,a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cong (R/I)[x]/(\overline{a_1},\ldots,\overline{a_n})$ where $\overline{a_i}$ is the image of $a_i$ in $(R/I)[x]$.

Try the obvious map $R[x]\to (R/I)[x]/(\overline{a_1},\ldots,\overline{a_n})$ defined something like

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x^i\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+I)x^i+(\overline{a_1},\ldots,\overline{a_n})$$

Check surjectivity, and then apply the FIT.

In your case, the above fact tells us what? It tells us that

$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x)$$

Why is this helpful?

Comment: I get it. So when we deal with quotient ring which involves polynomial ring, we can 'separate' them amd solve them one by one? For example, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @Idonknow Exactly! $R[x]/(I,x)\cong (R/I)[x]/(x)\cong R/I$.

Comment: Then how about $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ ? Actually I am not quite understand the fact that you provide in the first line

Comment: @Idonknow Which part don't you understand? Also, what about that ring? You may want to ask whatever question it is in another thread. The ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is better thought about $\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]$ where $\varepsilon^2=0$. Not very insightful, I know, but I don't know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Try to justify each of the following steps (with $\,\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\,$):

$$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle2,x\rangle\cong\left(\;\Bbb Z[x]/\langle 2\rangle\;\right)\left(\;\langle 2,x\rangle/\langle 2\rangle\;\right)\cong\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle x\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2$$

For example, you can define

$$\rho:\langle 2,x\rangle\to\langle x\rangle\;,\;\;\rho(2f(x)+xh(x)):=xh(x)\;,\;\;\ker\rho=\ldots ?$$

$$\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z_2[x]\;,\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(x)\pmod 2\;,\;\;\ker\phi=\ldots ?$$

$$\psi:\Bbb Z_2[x]\to\Bbb Z_2\;,\;\;\psi(f(x)):=f(0)\;,\;\;\ker\psi=\ldots ?$$

Of course, the very last isomorphism also *almost* follows from the fact that $\,\langle x\rangle\le\Bbb Z_2[x]\,$ is a maximal ideal

Comment: I followed your work formally using the isomorphism theorems, but is there a way to see intuitively why this isomorphism is true? I would have never guessed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)\:$ has $\,2\,$ elements, since $\rm\ mod\ (x,2)\!:\ f(x) \equiv f(0)\ mod\ 2\equiv 1\ \ or\ \ 0,\:$ and $\rm\: 1\not\equiv 0 \:$ (else $\rm\:1\in (2,x)\:\Rightarrow\:1 = 2 f + x g\stackrel{x\,=\,0}{\Rightarrow} 1 = 2\,f(0),\:$ contra $\rm\:f(0)\in\Bbb Z).$